Why does the Bible identify Mitsrayim with Egypt?
Abraham went to Mitsrayim c. 2000 BCE. At that time the Egyptians knew themselves as Kemet, not Misr. The earliest reference to the name Misr to my knowledge is from the Amarna Letters  c. 1350 BCE. This is after the Hebrews reached Israel. How do we explain this?

Mitsrayim/misr originate from the semitic root, designating this country. So it is reasonable that Egyptians would adopt this name after Arabic became the dominant language in Egypt.

Apparently it is the Hebrew name for Egypt, so Abraham would call it that before the Egyptians themselves did.

We have a [hermeneutics.se] site where this might be better.

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s). In this case, including the two Wikipedia links supports @RogerV.'s assertion.

It seems rather like the WikiPedia link to Mitsrayim (which a user helpfully edited into the question) answers the question right up in the second paragraph ("Linguistic Analysis"). Is there something that still isn't clear to you about it after reading that?

I see this has been nominated for re-open. Can anyone clarify if the issues that led to closure have been addressed?

@MCW I didn't think that the closing reasons are valid. For one, the Wikipedia article, contrary to TED, does not actually explain why the Hebrews used something other than what the Egyptians actually used for themselves. And at least to me it's asking about it from an historical point of view: what were the events that led to this group to do something unexpected (unexpected in the mind of the OP). It isn't asking it from a biblical perspective, a religious perspective, etc, but an historical one.

In this case, the "close" voters are misinformed, perhaps due to the religious nature of the subject. Yet it's inherently no different from asking why do the French call Germany Allemagne, which, by the way, is an acceptable question here already.

@Mcw. I have studied wikipedia. There is much discussion of misr at 1500 bce. There is no discussion at 1900 bce. I think my question is valid. In fact, the one answer helps. –
Bharat Jhunjhunwala

@cmw - That's fair. Close voters can be wrong, and the people who think so have no way to cast their votes until its closed.

@T.E.D. Right, so that's why I nominated it for re-opening and explained my reasoning. (And looking over it, "misinformed" is probably the wrong word, but I can't edit my comments any further.)

There are two elements to this. One has to do with the age of the story of Abraham, and other has to do with the promulgation of the name Misri (and its variants).
I.
First, Genesis (from which the story of Abraham as we have it comes) wasn't composed until the first millennium BCE. The figure of Abraham in Genesis is not historical, but are myths and legends the ancient Hebrews told about their foundation.
We know from other anachronisms that it had to be composed only in the Iron Age (e.g. since it presumes that iron working was widely known), and some even place the final version of Genesis to when Judah was part of the Persian empire.
So when telling the story of Abraham, Iron Age writers use the name for Egypt most familiar to them, that is, Mizraim.
(For a lay overview of the dating of Genesis, you should check out these sources:

Finkelstein & Silberman 2001, The Bible Unearthed.
Philip Davies 1992, In Search of Ancient Israel.
William G. Dever 2003, Who Were the Early Israelites and Where Did They Come From?)

II.
The second is more linguistic. Even if Kemet was used in Egypt, the Hebrews probably learned the name from their more worldly neighbors.
It's not clear (to me, at least) whether the Akkadian word (which you note in your question) or the Hebrew one has direct priority, but it's very likely that the closer linguistic contacts (and in the Iron Age, cultural contacts as well) between Semitic speaking peoples led to a promulgation of a shared demonym in all the languages.
For the same reason, from Greek, Latin and her daughter languages use a variant of the name Egypt instead.
Also, once a name is adopted, it's difficult to change. The English name for Deutschland has long been Germany, and I don't see that changing any time soon. And despite Myanmar really pushing for that name, so many still colloquially use the name Burma. In antiquity, authorities didn't try to push official names like this, so an adopted demonym would be even stickier.

@Roger. The question would be why the Hebrew would call it misr when there is no evidence anywhere for that name. One does not pull out a word out of the blue and apply it to another country.

On answer I. Once we assume the misr was redacted, the question still remains wherefrom the name misr was taken or what were the origins of the name before redaction. There is no antecedent to this name to my knowledge.

On answer II. Using variant of Egypt would be acceptable. But here we have a previously unknown name being applied to a country. The iron age solution also does not work because it is not explained how that name arose whether by aakadians, ugaruts or whoever.

@BharatJhunjhunwala I think you meant to post that reply to Roger under your question. He can't see it here when you post it under this answer.

Regarding the etymology, unfortunately, scholars aren't enturely sure. Wiktionary lists a couple guesses, but they're only hypothetical. It's possible it's an exonym or a rarer endonym that just happened to get adopted by Semitic speakers. Think e.g. how Rome's interactions with the Graii led to many languages adopting an adjectival form of it (Graecus -> Greek, etc.) as the name for all of the Hellenes. (My bet, for what it's worth, is on the Akkadian misru, "border".)

See also this blog post for more etymological musings.

Cmw. Pl help. I don't know how to reply on this forum.

@BharatJhunjhunwala Under your question, before you get to my answer, you see "Add Comment"? Click on that. I'll open up the box to reply to Roger there. If you want me to go into more detail (if I can!) you can just keep responding here. If you feel this answers the question as best as you can, you can click on the check mark. If you want to re-open this, you'll probably have to edit your question. My guess is to at the very least explain in the question why the Wikipedia article was unsatisfying. That shouldn't be hard, though, since I agree that it doesn't answer your question.
